# C# get class name from User Input

Tags: c#, .net, oop

In C#, how can I use user input or a stream to decide which class to work with? This example uses `Console.Readline()` however, the actual program will be deciding which class to use based on data from a stream that is read in a loop. This just simplifies an example of the question:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            stock aapl = new stock(); //instantiate a class for Apple Stock
            stock fb = new stock();   //instantiate a class for Facebook Stock

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a symbol for Apple or Facebook");
            string symbol = Console.ReadLine(); //this should get the class to work on

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter yesterdays price for the symbol");
            double yestPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter Todays Price for the symbol");
            double currPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            //Assuming aapl was entered, how do I
            //set values for the appl member using
            //the symbol variable like this:
            symbol.YesterdaysPrice = yestPrice; 
            symbol.CurrentPrice = currPrice; 

        }
        class stock
        {
            private double yesterdayPrice;
            private double currentPrice;
            private double dailyGain;

            public double YesterdaysPrice
            {
                get { return yesterdayPrice; }
                set { yesterdayPrice = value; }
            }
            public double CurrentPrice
            {
                get { return currentPrice; }
                set { currentPrice = value; }
            }
            public double DailyGain
            {
                get { return currentPrice - yesterdayPrice; }
                // No need to ever set directly
            }
        }
```

Comment: `if (symbol == "fb") { fb.YesterdaysPrice = yestPrice; fb.CurrentPrice = currPrice; }`, similarly for apple... Thats the easiest way. Ideally if you had multple stocks, you would add them to a dictionary and look them up by key.

Comment: There are 500 symbols and way more values than just two prices. What you are suggesting would basically create a 1000+ line switch statement

Comment: No, read the second part, add the symbols to a dictionary and then look them up by key, still a 3 line "if" statement.

Comment: Are you suggesting a `Dictionary` of `<string,object>` where object is the class member?

Comment: Almost, I'm suggesting using `Dictionary<string, stock>` where the string is the stock symbol and "stock" is the instance of the stock for that symbol.

Comment: I think that is my answer but probably a bit over my head. Can you post an answer with a short example?

Comment: I added an answer with an example.

Comment: Just checked it off as the correct answer, Man was that easier. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using a dictionary to solve this problem:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, stock> stocks = new Dictionary<string, stock>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        //Add the initial stocks here if desired.

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a symbol");
        string symbol = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter yesterdays price for the symbol");
        double yestPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Todays Price for the symbol");
        double currPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        if (stocks.ContainsKey(symbol))     //The dictionary contains the stock
        {
            stocks[symbol].YesterdaysPrice = yestPrice;
            stocks[symbol].CurrentPrice = currPrice;
        }
        else
        {
            //The stock wasn't found, we can either say invalid stock, or add one like this:
            stocks[symbol] = new stock()
            {
                YesterdaysPrice = yestPrice,
                CurrentPrice = currPrice;
            };
        }
    }
```

The dictionary is declared at the top and will hold all the entered symbols. After the user enters the symbol and the data, the `if` statement checks to see if a stock with that symbol already exists, and if it does, it updates its values. Just a quick note, I created the dictionary with an argument of `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` so that the user could enter AAPL or aapl, or aApL and it would all match the same stock, by default it is case sensitive and would create different stocks for those.

If the stock doesn't exist, you could tell the user that its an invalid stock, or you could just add the stock since you have all the data needed to do so. I showed the example of adding a new stock with an inline initializer for the price properties.

Answer (score 0):

Ron is suggesting to do as follows

```
        static readonly IDictionary<string, Stock> Stocks = new Dictionary<string, Stock>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a symbol for Apple or Facebook");
            var symbol = Console.ReadLine(); //this should get the class to work on

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter yesterdays price for the symbol");
            var yestPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter Todays Price for the symbol");
            var currPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            Stock stock;
            if (Stocks.ContainsKey(symbol))
                stock = Stocks[symbol];
            else
            {
                stock=new Stock();
                Stocks[symbol] = stock;
            }


            stock.YesterdaysPrice = yestPrice;
            stock.CurrentPrice = currPrice;

        }
```

Comment: This one doesn't actually work because you are declaring a class with a name that is not known. All that is known is that the variable that holds the name for the class is `symbol`. Can't get either one to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Well then first of all, you orignal sample does not make much sense. you have a variable "symbol" which you are reading from console as string, then you are trying to "symbol.YesterdaysPrice=yestPrice" ??? i think its a typo. you need to explain your requirement clearly.